# Very basic pagination filtering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I already have filtering, page limit working.

But what I cant do is when I click the page show only the page 2 customers.

For example if I have 6 customers with a limit of 5 for page, page 1 should be 5 customers and page 2 should be 1. But when I click the page 2 it doesn't do anything..

Any help?

Code:

```
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Customer ID&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('customerID');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">First Name&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('firstName');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Last Name&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('lastName');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Identity Card ID&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('identityCardID');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">TAX ID&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('taxID');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Account ID&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('accountID');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Account Type&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('accountType');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Gender&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('gender');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Birth Date&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('birthDate');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Street&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('street');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Postal Code&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('postalCode');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">City&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('city');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Country&nbsp;<a uib-tooltip="Sort by" ng-click="vm.sortBy('country');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="text-center" ng-repeat="customer in filteredCustomers = (vm.customers | filter : vm.search | orderBy : vm.propertyName : vm.reverse | limitTo:vm.itemsPerPage:vm.itemsPerPage*(page-1))">
                        <td>{{customer.CUSTOMER_ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.FIRST_NAME}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.LAST_NAME}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.IDENTITY_CARD_NUMBER}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.TAX_IDENTIFICATION}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.ACCOUNT_ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.CUSTOMER_GENDER_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.BIRTH_DATE}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.STREET_ADDRESS}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.POSTAL_CODE}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.CITY}}</td>
                        <td>{{customer.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button ng-click="vm.selectCustomer(customer)" class="btn btn-default">Select</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center" ng-show="!filteredCustomers.length"><b class="color-red">No Customers found with this filter.</b></div>
                <button ipp-command="complete" id="completeActivity" style="display:none;"></button>
                <span class="pull-left">Showing {{filteredCustomers.length}} customers of {{vm.totalItems}} found.</span>
                <ul class="pull-right" uib-pagination total-items="vm.totalItems" ng-change="vm.pageChanged()" ng-model="vm.currentPage" ng-model="vm.currentPage" items-per-page="vm.itemsPerPage"></ul>
```

controller

```
 //table pagination
        vm.totalItems = vm.customers.length;
        vm.currentPage = 1;
        vm.itemsPerPage = "5"; // default value
        vm.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show
        vm.shownItems = vm.totalItems / vm.itemsPerPage;
        if(vm.shownItems < vm.totalItems)
            vm.shownItems = vm.totalItems;
        else
            vm.shownItems = vm.currentPage * vm.itemsPerPage;

        vm.setPage = function (pageNo) {
            vm.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        vm.pageChanged = function() {
            var startPos = vm.currentPage * vm.itemsPerPage;
            console.log(startPos);
            vm.filteredCustomers = vm.customers.slice(startPos, startPos + vm.itemsPerPage);
        };

        vm.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
            vm.itemsPerPage = num;
            vm.currentPage = 1; //reset to first page
        };

        // table ordering
        vm.propertyName = 'customerID';
        vm.reverse = true;

        vm.sortBy = function(propertyName) {
            vm.reverse = (vm.propertyName === propertyName) ? !vm.reverse : false;
            vm.propertyName = propertyName;
        };
```

Comment: Why are you setting `vm.itemsPerPage` to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) directive , It contains lot of functionality , you can also customize your template and can also add server side paging.